# std::dynamic_pointer_cast successful call on non initialized class

Tags: c++, dynamic, casting, smart-pointers

I wrote a minimal example to test some behaviour. I tried to get `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to fail but encountered unexpected behaviour.

Here is the minimal example that I used:

```
//virtual_ipsum.h
class virtual_ipsum
{
public:
    virtual_ipsum() { }
    virtual ~virtual_ipsum() { }
};
```

```
//derived_lorem.h
#include "virtual_ipsum.h"
#include <iostream>
#define UUID_DERIVED_LOREM_RANDOM 2 //rolled it myself
class derived_lorem :
    public virtual_ipsum
{
public:
    derived_lorem(){ }
    ~derived_lorem(){ }
    void o(){ std::cout << "lorem" << std::endl; };
};
```

```
//derived_adipiscing.h
#include "virtual_ipsum.h"
#include <iostream>
#define UUID_DERIVED_ADIPISCING_RANDOM 24 //rolled it myself
class derived_adipiscing :
    public virtual_ipsum
{
public:
    derived_adipiscing(){ }
    ~derived_adipiscing(){ }
    void elit(){ std::cout << "donec" << std::endl; };
};
```

```
//server.h
#include <memory>
#include "virtual_ipsum.h"
//note that the header of the server can not contain the derived classes.

class server
{
public:
    server() {}
    ~server() {}
    std::shared_ptr<virtual_ipsum> getDerivedClassByUUID(int UUID);
};
```

```
//server.cpp
#include "server.h"
#include "derived_lorem.h"
std::shared_ptr<virtual_ipsum> server::getDerivedClassByUUID(int UUID)
{
    // after careful examination of the UUID the
    // server will send the correct derived class
    return std::make_shared<derived_lorem>();
}
```

```
//client.h
#include <memory>
#include "server.h"
class client
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<server> s;
public:
    client(std::shared_ptr<server> s) : s(s){}
    ~client(){}
    void dolor();
    void consectetur();
};
```

```
//client.cpp
#include "client.h"
#include "derived_lorem.h"
#include "derived_adipiscing.h"
#include <memory>
void client::dolor()
{
    std::shared_ptr<virtual_ipsum> sit = s->getDerivedClassByUUID(UUID_DERIVED_LOREM_RANDOM);
    std::shared_ptr<derived_lorem> amet = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<derived_lorem>(sit);
    amet->o();
}
void client::consectetur()
{
    std::shared_ptr<virtual_ipsum> felis = s->getDerivedClassByUUID(UUID_DERIVED_LOREM_RANDOM);
    //everything should crash and burn
    std::shared_ptr<derived_adipiscing> mauris = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<derived_adipiscing>(felis);
    mauris->elit();
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <memory>
#include "server.h"
#include "client.h"

void main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<server> s = std::make_shared<server>();
    std::shared_ptr<client> c = std::make_shared<client>(s);
    c->dolor();
    c->consectetur();
}
```

The output on my machine is:
[image: output of minimal example]

The call to `c->consectetur();` should fail since the server returned the wrong derived class. Instead, the cast is not only successful but also completed like it should have if it were the correct class.

How can I detect that problem on the client side during casting?

Comment: if `amet` is `nullptr` (due to failure of a dynamic cast) then it's UB. you can check if it's non-empty

Comment: Ah, i added a check for that and now the code detects it. Thanks. Is the execution of c->consectetur() undefined and i am just lucky or is it well defined since i inlined it in the header?

Comment: It's undefined behavior

Comment: `main` must not return `void`. Also, this example is hardly minimal.

Comment: @user2079303 sorry for the long minimal example. I got carried away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the above comments point out:

- calling `mauris->elit();` is undefined.
- std::shared_ptr can simply be null checked.
- void main makes people unhappy

Changing the implementation of client to the following resolves the issue.

```
#include "client.h"
#include "derived_lorem.h"
#include "derived_adipiscing.h"
#include <memory>

void client::dolor()

{
    std::shared_ptr<virtual_ipsum> sit = s->getDerivedClassByUUID(UUID_DERIVED_LOREM_RANDOM);
    std::shared_ptr<derived_lorem> amet = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<derived_lorem>(sit);
    if (amet)
    {
        amet->o();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "amet is null" << std::endl;
    }

}

void client::consectetur()
{
    std::shared_ptr<virtual_ipsum> felis = s->getDerivedClassByUUID(UUID_DERIVED_LOREM_RANDOM);
    //everything should crash and burn
    std::shared_ptr<derived_adipiscing> mauris = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<derived_adipiscing>(felis);

    if (mauris)
    {
        mauris->elit();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "mauris is null" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

new output:
[image]

Comment: *"calling `mauris->elit();` is undefined."* only when `mauris` can be `nullptr`